# Call object in another class in another file with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, methods, call

I have a public class A in a file called `A.designer.cs` and there is a textbox object called `Textbox1` in there that I want to use. It is declared as:

```
public DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView textbox1
```

I want to use it in my `b.cs` file, which is of a public partial class b. How do I call the `Textbox1` in class A?

I tried

```
A.Grid.GridView.textbox1.Text = "hi"
```

but it is giving me the error that the file

> "does not contain a definition for "grid"".

Comment: How does it make sense to have a `GridView` object referred to by a field whose name suggests that it refers to a `TextBox`?

Comment: Seems like this is overcomplicated and you're getting confused - why would you try to reference a member of A called `textbox1` by calling `A.Grid.GridView.textbox1`?

Answer (score 0):

It's a public instance member of class `A` so you need an instance `A` and you can then access its `textbox1` field.  You've already done this same thing a hundred times before with various other members of various other types.  Why try to make it harder this time?

Answer (score 0):

the scenario doesn't make much sense to me but if that's the case.. Do it as usual.

```
//get a instance of A, something like
A a = new A();

//access by: 
a.textbox1
```

But really you may want to think about why accessing a gridview from outside.